# XML Hebrew reading as question mark

Tags: xml, groovy, utf-8

I have an XML with English and Hebrew.
I'm trying to read the XML with groovy using File.io and charset UTF-8 but the Hebrew part is giving me question marks.

```
File xmlFile = new File(inputPath)
LOGGER.info(xmlFile.getText("UTF-8"))
```

The English part are showing good, but the Hebrew is only question marks.

The XML is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mediaRequest>
   <key1>Test</key1>
   <Comment>לבדיקה</Comment>
</mediaRequest>
```

Comment: What font is being used?  The question mark is probably do to character not being in the Font.

Comment: What do you mean what font? How can I know what font is used?

Comment: What are you using to display results?

Comment: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: If you are reading from a log file than to tool that opens the file determines the Font that is used.  The library you are using want a string and the string will contain an encoding method with character set.  You are reading a UTF-8 file which means there is not encoding.  So you have to encode the bytes using an encoding method.  So you need to use Windows Encoding 1255.

Comment: I open the log file with notepad++ and I also send a mail with the xml as text. In both outputs there are either question marks or unknown characters (in variations of encoders that I tried to use). I tried using "windows-1255" like you suggested but it's still not a good output.

Comment: Try changing Font in notepadd++ : https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/notepad-plus-plus-change-font.html?force_isolation=true#:~:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20Settings%20tab,from%20the%20Font%20size%20section.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].